How do i read NTAG424 NFC Tags in my flutter app, i keep getting an "NDEF not found error"
I am working on a flutter project using flutter_nfc_kit to scan(read) an nfc tag for a uri payload and then make use of the payload for other activities i am not doing any writing, the tag type in focus is the NTAG424 NFC TAG, i have no issues when working with TYPE 2 TAGS.
The problem is the functionality works for Type 2 tags (NTAG213, 216 etc), but when i try to scan a NTAG424 tag it returns an "ndef not found error", I use flutter_nfc_kit: ^3.5.2, i have tested with nfc tools like "NFC tools" and "NXP TagWriter", so i confirm the tag is functional and i can see the encoded uri.
Below is the relevant code for the scanning functionality.
Future<void> _startNfcScan(BuildContext context) async {
  try {
    // Show the bottom sheet for Android (iOS already has a native NFC prompt)
    if (!Platform.isIOS) {
      await _showReadyToScanSheet(context);
    }

    // Start the NFC polling session
    var tag = await FlutterNfcKit.poll(timeout: Duration(seconds: 10));

    // Check if NDEF is available and read NDEF content
    if (tag.ndefAvailable == true) {
      // Read decoded NDEF records
      List<ndef.NDEFRecord> ndefRecords = await FlutterNfcKit.readNDEFRecords();

      if (ndefRecords.isNotEmpty) {
        var firstRecord = ndefRecords.first;

        // Ensure the payload is not null
        if (firstRecord.payload != null && firstRecord.payload!.isNotEmpty) {
          // Manually decode the compressed URI
          String decodedUrl = _decodeUriPayload(firstRecord.payload!);

          // Log or print the full decoded URL
          print('Decoded URL from NFC tag: $decodedUrl');

          // Now you have the full URL,do something with it
          await _doSomething(context, decodedUrl);

          // Show the "Scan Complete" bottom sheet after scanning
          if (!Platform.isIOS) {
            await _showScanCompleteSheet(context);
          }
        } else {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text('No payload found on the NFC tag.')),
          );
        }
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('No NDEF records found on the tag.')),
        );
      }
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('NDEF not available on this tag.')),
      );
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle errors during NFC scanning
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text('Failed to read NFC tag: $e')),
    );
  } finally {
    // Finish the NFC session
    await FlutterNfcKit.finish(iosAlertMessage: 'Scan Complete');
  }
}

String _decodeUriPayload(List<int> payload) {
  // The first byte in the URI payload is the prefix byte
  final int prefixByte = payload[0];

  // The rest of the payload is the actual URI content
  final uriContent = utf8.decode(payload.sublist(1));

  // Map the prefix byte to the correct URL scheme
  const prefixMap = {
    0x00: '', // No prefix
    0x01: 'http://www.',
    0x02: 'https://www.',
    0x03: 'http://',
    0x04: 'https://',
    // 
  };

  // Get the prefix based on the prefix byte
  final prefix = prefixMap[prefixByte] ?? '';

  // Return the full URL by combining the prefix with the URI content
  return prefix + uriContent;
}



Seeing the uri: "so i confirm the tag is functional and i can see the encoded uri" is not the same as the NDEF capability. What does happen if you tap the NTAG424 to the (Android) device ? Does it open the browser and show the page behind the uri ? If not your tag is not having a NDEF message stored on it but the named apps are showing the "raw" content of the tag. Please confirm the action, thanks.

The other option is to use the "NXP Taginfo" Save feature, which saves the tag info to an xml file which can then be posted to here if @MichaelFehr 's basic test of the Ndef does not work.

@MichaelFehr  on android the default native action triggers and opens the browser with the url encoded on the tag(which i need to fix) , the focus now is more on ios devices, when i place the phone on the tag the native popup comes up at the top prompting to open the browser, but i still get the "ndef not available on this tag" error when scanning with my flutter app.
So please explain more on what you mean by "raw" content of the tag, and how do i go about making my code read that raw content and decode the uri.

As always commented by @Andrew, please use the NXP's TagInfo app to get the raw content and post it here (please edit your question, do not use a comment for this). Embed the Log FIle in code tags for much better readability.

I'm posting this as an answer since this is what worked for me:

I had to switch to using nfc_manager
Then added this to info.plist and now i can successfully scan NTAG424 DNA TAGS with my app.
 <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes</key>
   <array>
     <string>8005</string>
     <string>8008</string>
     <string>0003</string>
     <string>fe00</string>
     <string>90b7</string>
     <string>927a</string>
     <string>86a7</string>
   </array>
  <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
  <array>
      <string>A0000002471001</string>
      <string>A000000003101001</string>
      <string>A000000003101002</string>
      <string>A0000000041010</string>
      <string>A0000000042010</string>
      <string>A0000000044010</string>
      <string>44464D46412E44466172653234313031</string>
      <string>D2760000850100</string>
      <string>D2760000850101</string>
      <string>00000000000000</string>
  </array>



So it seems to be more of an incomplete setup issue, creaed an article on it for those interested in the full story.
https://medium.com/@timidev34/solving-the-ndef-not-available-error-when-working-with-ntag424-nfc-tags-on-ios-in-flutter-26928edd717f
